# What is this function about?

Tags: functions, notation

I have found this [Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE2PE.png) in my homework, but I don't know what it is asking.
Assuming x is a binary input should I repeat it 3 times? or doing anything else?
Exactly, what should I compute with her?

[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE2PE.png)

Thanks you

Comment: Provide some more context, please. What is this problem about?

Comment: I need to complete a software to be computed by a Turing machine, but I don't know this formal notation so I need to understand what this function ask me to calculate to understand which operation this function do with the input. I don't asking you to do my homework since I have to try first. I only need to understand this formal function semantic.

Comment: [How to format maths in MathJax.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), sometimes also called the characteristic function.

In general: $\chi_A(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in A \\ 0, & x \notin A \end{cases}$

So the value of your function will be $1$ if $x=3$ and it will be $0$ if $x \ne 3$.

Comment: Thanks you! I can do my homework now!